# ¿cómo escribo la hora extra para que valga doble?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
**using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ejercicio13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double horasNormales, horasExtra, nomina;

               
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        const double kRet = 0.18;
        

        private void total_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            horasNormales = double.Parse(horaN.Text);
            
            horasExtra = double.Parse(horaE.Text);

            horasExtra = horasNormales * 2;
            nomina = (horasNormales + horasExtra) * kRet;

            nominaT.Text = nomina.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Un trabajador a lo largo del mes trabaja un número de horas normales y un número
de horas extras. Las horas extras se pagan el doble que las horas normales. Realizar
un programa en el que se introduzcan el número de horas trabajadas (normales y
extras) y la paga por hora normal, y se calcule la nomina mensual, aplicando una
retención del 18%.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes? SOlo pusiste un enunciado.

Comment: Como se trata de un ejercicio, te propongo darte algunas pistas para que intentes resolverlo por tu cuenta. Por lo que veo, el problema está en la interpretación del enunciado. De su lectura se puede notar que necesitas obtener 3 valores pero en el código solo tienes 2.

Answer (score 2):

Buen trabajo @marxal. Ahora que tu respuesta está casi lista la voy a complementar con algunos comentarios para que los tengas en cuenta a futuro.

En primer lugar, el error que le queda está relacionado con la retención.
En términos simples, una retención es un valor que debes **restar** al sueldo o salario. [Ver más](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retenci%C3%B3n_fiscal)

En este caso, el enunciado plantea una retención del 18%. El valor de la variable `nomina` en tu respuesta contiene justamente el 18% y debería contener el resultado `(horasNormales + horasExtra) * precioH` **menos** el 18% por lo tanto esa instrucción debería ser:

```
nomina = (horasNormales + horasExtra) * precioH * (1 - kRet);
```

o tal vez en varios pasos

```
nomina = (horasNormales + horasExtra) * precioH;
double retencion = nomina * kRet;
double nominaResultado = nomina - retencion;
```

Ambos bloques de instrucciones son equivalentes, el punto aquí es ilustrar la idea de una retención.

Luego que tengas el programa operativo, te sugiero probar escribir cualquier cosa que no sea un número en los Textbox donde capturas los valores y luego click en el botón para calcular. Esto producirá una exception.

Lo que quiero destacar con esto es que no puedes confiar en que la información que recibes de fuentes externas (en este caso el usuario) sea exactamente lo que esperas recibir y por eso debes incluir validaciones.

Mi recomendación es que en lugar de utilizar `double.Parse(...);` utilices [`double.TryParse(...);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

La idea del patrón `.TryParse()` es proveer un mecanismo de conversión que no produce Excepciones.

- Cuando la conversión es exitosa, su resultado es `true` y asigna el valor convertido al parámetro de salida (`horasNormales/horasExtra` en el código más adelante).
- Cuando la conversión falla, su resultado es `false` y el parámetro de salida es cero.

De esta forma, el código sugerido para las conversiones sería:

```
if(double.TryParse(horaN.Text, out horasNormales) && double.TryParse(horaE.Text, out horasExtra))
{
    // En este punto las conversiones fueron exitosas 
    // y puedes hacer los cálculos
}
else
{
    // En este punto alguna de las conversiones no se pudo realizar
    // y los cálculos no son posibles
}
```

Espero que mis comentarios y esta explicación sean de utilidad en tu camino de aprendizaje.

Comment: Muchas gracias pablo, voy aprobar todo lo que me dices, aunque en ese temario aún no hemos dado el if y el else y tampoco el tryparse, pero de todas formas me sirve para probar cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de conceptos (tal como dice @PabloGutierrez),

1. definir que horas laboradas no es lo mismo que valor hora.
2. Además que tomas el número de horas laboradas debes de tener otro textbox que capture el valor por horas; por ejemplo se valora la hora normal en 15 dolares, tener en cuenta que este valor puede variar según el trabajador así que se debe indicar cuanto es el valor de hora trabajada por empleado

entonces tienes que definir el valor hora y realizar la multiplicación hora por su valor:

```
horasNormales = double.Parse(horaN.Text) * 15;//coloque 15 por ejemplo 15 dolares la hora

horasExtra = double.Parse(horaE.Text) * (15 * 2);//se puede obviar el 15 * 2 colocar 30 directamente
```

por ultimo realizar el computo de horas laboradas y remuneradas:

```
nomina = (horasNormales + horasExtra) * kRet;
```

Indique el computo directo con números(15) pero realizarias el parseo de lo que captures del textbox de valor hora.

Comment: Voy a insistir con la lectura y comprensión del enunciado. Además de lo que mencioné en mi comentario original y la invitación para que @marxal intentara resolverlo por cuenta propia, hay otro error y también está en la solución que propones. Debo destacar que mi interés con lo que planteo, es estimular el análisis y la comprensión de un planteamiento antes de comenzar a escribir código sin tener una idea clara del objetivo.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, estoy iniciándome a aprender programación en C# y ando muy perdido, estoy pensando en hacer algún curso de Udemy o algo por el estilo, estoy estudiando Daw en semipresencial y la verdad es que necesito un profesor.

Comment: @ger gracias por tu ayuda, lo he modificado sin poner lo de las horas a 15 pero creando una variable del precio de las horas y funciona

Answer (score -1):

he creado la variable precioH

```
 double horasNormales, horasExtra, nomina, precioH;
```

y luego he modificado lo de las horas normales

```
 precioH = double.Parse(precioHora.Text);

        horasNormales = double.Parse(horaN.Text)* precioH;
        
        horasExtra = double.Parse(horaE.Text) * (precioH*2);

        
        nomina = (horasNormales + horasExtra) * precioH* kRet;
```

Y creo que ya funciona correctamente

Comment: Esto es la respuesta a tu pregunta? podrias explicarla entonces?

Comment: Claro, multiplicaría las horas normales por el precio de la hora y para la hora extra lo mismo pero por dos para que la hora sea más cara